# I need to pick out some numbers out of a string with commas mixed in

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, input, max

So Im doing a little Right Triangle Checker

```
    def RightTriangleChecker(Number1,Number2,Number3):
        AllNumbers=[Number1,Number2,Number3]
        Hypotonuse=max(AllNumbers)
        if(Number1**2+Number2**2==Number3**2):
            print "This is a right triangle."
        else:
           print"This is not a right triangle."
```

And the problem is that when I get the numbers out I get one number, comma and another number. Or some combination of those (depending on the input) i was wondering if anyone could help me find a way to just get the numbers.

Comment: Specifically, what @AvinashRaj is asking is for at the part of your code that shows your issue.  You haven't posted the part that gets any numbers out.

Comment: Oh, I completely didnt notice that sorry here we go, again Im new to coding so this will be kind of basic.

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "26, 43, 25"
nums = [int(i) for i in s.split(",")]
```

also, I would rewrite your function as

```
def is_right_triangle(x, y, z):
    a, b, c = sorted([x, y, z])
    return a*a + b*b == c*c
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution.

Comment: Im sorry but I am very new to code (like noob #1) so what does the top part do?

Comment: First it splits the string by commas, giving `["26", " 43", "25"]`; then it applies `int` to each substring, converting it to a number, giving `[26, 43, 25]`. This is called a list comprehension (apply a function to each item in a list, and return the results as a list).

Answer (score 0):

```
    def RightTriangleChecker(Number1,Number2,Number3):
AllNumbers=[Number1,Number2,Number3]
Hypotonuse=max(AllNumbers)
if(Number1**2+Number2**2==Number3**2):
    print "This is a right triangle."
else:
    print"This is not a right triangle."


    def Retry():
        Answer==raw_input("Retry?")
        if (Answer=="Yes"):
            TriangleLength=raw_input("What are the lengths of the sides?         (Please put commas in-between each number)")
       RightTriangleChecker(TriangleLength[1],TriangleLength[2],TriangleLength[3])
else:
    exit(0)

    Original=raw_input("Would you like to use this program?")
    if (Original=="Yes"):
            TriangleLength=raw_input("What are the lengths of the sides? (Please put commas in-between each number)")
        RightTriangleChecker(TriangleLength[1],TriangleLength[2],TriangleLength[3])
    if (Original=="No"):
            exit(0)
    Retry()
```